Transitioning from O1 to B1/B2
I am currently on an O1A visa and residing in the US, and would like to transfer to B1/B2 visa while I figure out my future career options. I do not yet have my O1A visa stamped on my passport yet. My questions are:

Can I apply for the B1/B2 visa while I am in the USA?
Do I need to leave the US and re-enter to apply/activate B1/B2?


First, let's get the terminology straight. A US "visa" is a sticker that takes up a whole page of your passport, says "VISA" on it. US visas are solely for entry to the US, and you can (with rare exceptions) only get a US visa at a US consulate outside the US. What you call "visa stamped" is a visa, and you do not have an O1 visa (not that it is relevant to this question).
So no, you cannot get a B visa while in the US, nor do you need a visa while in the US, since visas are solely for entry. You can apply for a Change of Status while in the US, by filing I-539, to change to B2 status. This does not give you a "visa". If you were to leave the US and then wish to enter the US into B2 status, then you would need to have gotten a B2 visa from a US consulate.
Note that if you stop working, you remain in O1 status until 60 days after you stop working, or until your I-94 expires, whichever is first. If that period of time is sufficient for you to take your next steps, you do not need to change to B2 status.

IIRC there are some conditions under which automatic visa revalidation can result in a change of nonimmigrant status, but whether that could be useful in a case like this one, I do not know.

Could you elaborate further @phoog?

@user32545 having refreshed my memory at https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/41.112 (see item (d)), this means that if you change status in the US you can leave the US and re-enter in the new status provided you don't travel outside North America, don't stay away for more than 30 days, and meet a few other conditions as well.  My recollection that it was possible to use automatic revalidation to change status was incorrect.  It can be used after a change of status.
